# How to disambiguate between two Actions in ApiController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm having problems creating a route or other configuration that will disambiguate two Get methods.  Here's a sample  class:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController

   public User[] GetMany([FromUri]int[] id)
   {
      // returns all users requested by id
   }

   public User[] GetAll()
   {
      // returns all users
   }

}
```

I'd like `myhost/api/users` to map to `GetAll`, and `myhost/api/users?id=123` to map to `GetMany`.

Right now they both yield a 500 error because both methods are matched as possible actions for both URIs.

Here's my route:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "AllUsersRoute",
            routeTemplate: "api/users",
            defaults: new { },
            constraints: new { }
        );
```

While I know in this simple example, the `GetMany` method could be changed to treat an empty id list as a request for all, but in more complex scenarios this might not be the case.

Note, I'm using MVC 4 Web API, Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with action selection.

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/821

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/322

Comment: Thanks for that.  The first link is dead on what I was hitting.  I'll keep this open for a couple more days in case someone has a clever way to tweak the action selection mechanism to fix this issue, but otherwise this one is yourts.